# cakephp asyncronse job

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I would like to write a cron job that has to run a PHP script at 6am, 11am,2pm,4pm on each day.

Can you please help me with this? I wrote a shell task in shells and I want to run that task at the timings i said in the earlier statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this post sums up some of things that you will need

http://www.webbedit.co.uk/blog_posts/view/cakephp-shells-cron-job

in cake 2.1

the console is in app/Console/cake